# Python PIL paste() function one transparent image on another

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I want to draw one transparent/semi-transparent image on another. But paste() function, ruins my image.

I know about alpha_composite() function, but I need offset parameter (not in this example, but in my code I need it).

```py
from PIL import Image;

img_in_00 = Image.open( "./in_00.png" );

img_in_01 = Image.open( "./in_01.png" );

n_width, n_height = img_in_01.size;

img_out = Image.new( "RGBA", ( n_width, n_height ), ( 0, 0, 0, 0 ) );

img_out.paste( img_in_00, ( 0, 0 ), img_in_00 );

img_out.paste( img_in_01, ( 0, 0 ), img_in_01 );

img_out.save( "out.png", "PNG" );
```

What I expect: 
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRB5T.png)

What I get:
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8unr4.png)

Comment: If you would like some assistance, make it easy for those trying to help you. Please provide two **separate** input images and an output image showing the expected result. Please also include all `import` statements so we don't have to guess which modules you are using. Thank you.

Comment: Ok. I edited my post.

Comment: You don't appear to have provided what I requested...

Comment: So your image `img_in_01` is completely transparent and what you expect is to only have `img_in_00` as the output, correct? If not, please post your input images.